# Проблема точности при реализации нечеткого поиска

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, нечеткий-поиск

Я новичок в `python`, поэтому мои алгоритмы скорее всего неэффективны.
Реализую нечеткий поиск в курсовой для поиска ответа в базе.
Моя идея реализации.

1. Приведение базы в нормальный вид, то есть удаление служебных частей
   речи и лемматизация + стемминг Реализация удаления служебных частей
   речи:

   ```
   def serviceWordsPosition(word, wordAnalyser=pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()): #Анализатор типа слова
       return wordAnalyser.parse(word)[0].tag.POS

   def SentenceToBase(sentence): #Преобразование строки в базовый вид
       accomulatingString = ''
       words = sentence.split()
       functors_QuestionsToBase = {'INTJ', 'PRCL', 'CONJ', 'PREP'}
       for word in words:
           if serviceWordsPosition(word) not in functors_QuestionsToBase:
               accomulatingString += word + ' '
       return  accomulatingString

   def QuestionsToBase(QuestionsList): #Преобразование базы в базовый вид
       QuestionsListBaseForm = []
       for sentence in QuestionsList:
           QuestionsListBaseForm.append(SentenceToBase(sentence))
       return QuestionsListBaseForm
   ```
2. Приведение запрашиваемой фразы в нормальный вид

   ```
   def SentenceToRoot(sentence):
       morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
       sentence=' '.join([morph.normal_forms(w)[0] for w in sentence.split()])
       return sentence
   ```
3. С помощью расстояния левенштейна нахожу редакционное расстояние
   между каждой строкой в нормированной базе и фразой из запроса В
   используемой библиотеке, расстояние реализовано похожестью в %

   ```
   SimularitySum = []
   for questionsentence in QuestionDataBase:
           s = fuzz.ratio(questionsentence,messagebaseform)
           SimularitySum.append(s)
           print(questionsentence,messagebaseform,s)
   ```
4. Вывожу ответ соответствующий минимальному редакционному расстоянию

   ```
   print(AnswerDataBase[SimularitySum.index(max(SimularitySum))])
   ```

Проблема состоит в том, что точность результатов слишком мала. (по тестам 32-44%)
Как стоит улучшить алгоритм, чтобы повысить точность?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под базой? И задача в поиске одного слова или сочетания слов или предложения?

Comment: По 3 пункту: правильно я понял, вы сравниваете нормализованную строку из базы и не нормализованный запрос? Попробуйте сравнивать и то и другое в нормализованном виде.

Comment: @insolor, сравниваю обе строки в нормализированном виде, просто не вставил фрагмент

Comment: @Kirya522, как меряете точность результатов, 32-34% - это по сравнению с чем?

Comment: @insolor, попросил одногруппников по готовой базе составить неточные запросы(60 штук), 3 теста по 20 вопросов, и смотрел процент правильных ответов

Comment: Для неправильных ответов попробуйте выводить не 1 результат, а сразу все в порядке увеличения различия, может быть так получится понять в чем причина неточности.

Comment: @MaxU, есть документ excel хранящий в 1 столбце вопрос, во 2 столбце ответ, задача состоит в том, что с помощью неточного поиска найти конкретный вопрос из 1 столбца и вывести соответствующий ему ответ

Comment: @Kirya522, посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784306/211923) - может вам подойдет подобный подход. Трудно сказать не видя примеров ваших данных и "неточных запросов"...