# Как сравнить два списка по совпадениям слов в первом с предложениями во втором?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, list, nlp

Есть интересная задача, думаю как к ней поступиться. Есть 2-а списка: `а` содержит списко слов, `b` - 5 предложений.

Нужно подумать как лучше, циклом или может другим способом. Сравнить из `a` списка слова со всеми строками `b` списка, и выбрать из них топ 3 наиболее схожих, т.е. самых высоких по проценту совпадения.

```
a = ['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']
b = [
    'человек развивает свой ум'
    , 'мама любит котят'
    , 'мама ремонтирует раму'
    , 'папа моет рамы'
    , 'мама установила приложение'
    ]
```

Comment: Какая метрика схожести?

Comment: @dIm0n Сразу с козырей зашёл!

Comment: Так то можно стандартную функцию сортировки списка использовать, задав в качестве ключа `lambda`, которая будет будет обращаться к функции, которая посчитает "похожесть" элемента списка на ваш первый список. Но сначала надо сформулировать функцию похожести, да.

Comment: Нужен еще топ 3 сделать по самому высокому совпадению, подскажите куда двигаться) Нужно полное совпадение по словам, без окончаний и видоизменения слов.

Comment: Сколько совпадающих слов вы хотите получить для этих двух предложений - `0` или `3`: 1) `"Мамочка помыла все рамы"` 2) `"мама мыла раму"` ?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/783851/211923)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, круто и быстро. Но к сожалению не совсем то. У меня много значений будет и мне как-то надо преобразовать по процентам.Я не совсем корректно поставил условия( Пример ниже:                                                                                                                               import difflib def similarity(s1, s2): normalized1 = s1.lower() normalized2 = s2.lower() matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2) return matcher.ratio() similarity('мама', 'мама')

Comment: Ниже добавлен вариант 3 с использованием вашего кода с использованием библиотеки difflib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ниже приведено 3 варианта решения 1) без нормализации, 2) с нормализацией слов, 3) с использованием difflib.

**Вариант 1. Пример решения без нормализации слов:**

```
a = ['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']
b = [
    'человек развивает свой ум',
    'мама любит котят',
    'мама ремонтирует раму',
    'папа моет рамы',
    'мама установила приложение',
]

set1 = set(w.lower() for w in a)
print(set1)

# веса похожести для каждого словосочетания
w = [(s, len(set(s.lower().split()) & set1)) for s in b]
print(w)

# сортировка в убывающем порядке по весам
c = sorted(w, key=lambda el: -el[1])
print(c)

# Топ 3
print(c[:3])
```

Результаты работы кода:

```
{'мыла', 'раму', 'мама'}
[('человек развивает свой ум', 0), ('мама любит котят', 1), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('папа моет рамы', 0), ('мама установила приложение', 1), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0), ('Мама помыла раму', 2)]
[('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('Мама помыла раму', 2), ('мама любит котят', 1), ('мама установила приложение', 1), ('человек развивает свой ум', 0), ('папа моет рамы', 0), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0)]
[('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('Мама помыла раму', 2), ('мама любит котят', 1)]
```

**Вариант 2. Упрощенный вариант с нормализацией слов:**

```
import pymorphy2
from functools import lru_cache

a = ['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']
b = [
    'человек развивает свой ум',
    'мама любит котят',
    'мама ремонтирует раму',
    'папа моет рамы',
    'мама установила приложение',
    'Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят',
    'Мама помыла раму',
    'Маме моет мылом раму',
]

morphy = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
# Упрощенный метод нормализации слов, не совсем правильно преобразует слова:
# помыла-> помыть; мыла -> мыло; мамочка -> мамочка
# но правильно:
# маму -> мама, котят -> "котёнок", "мылом" -> "мыло"

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def normalize(word):
    return morphy.parse(word)[0].normal_form

set1 = set(normalize(w) for w in a)
print(set1)

# веса похожести для каждого словосочетания
w = [(s, len(set(normalize(w) for w in s.split()) & set1)) for s in b]
print(w)

# сортировка в убывающем порядке по весам
c = sorted(w, key=lambda el: -el[1])
print(c)

# Топ 3
print(c[:3])
```

Результаты работы кода варианта с нормализацией:

```
{'рам', 'мама', 'мыло'}
[('человек развивает свой ум', 0), ('мама любит котят', 1), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('папа моет рамы', 0), ('мама установила приложение', 1), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0), ('Мама помыла раму', 2), ('Маме моет мылом раму', 3)]
[('Маме моет мылом раму', 3), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('Мама помыла раму', 2), ('мама любит котят', 1), ('мама установила приложение', 1), ('человек развивает свой ум', 0), ('папа моет рамы', 0), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0)]
[('Маме моет мылом раму', 3), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 2), ('Мама помыла раму', 2)]
```

Pymorphy можно настроить и сделать чтобы он более точно определял нормальную форму слов.

**Вариант 3. С использованием difflib:**

```
import difflib

def similarity(s1, s2):
    normalized1 = s1.lower()
    normalized2 = s2.lower()
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2)
    return matcher.ratio()

a = ['мама', 'мыла', 'раму']
b = [
    'человек развивает свой ум',
    'мама любит котят',
    'мама ремонтирует раму',
    'папа моет рамы',
    'мама установила приложение',
    'Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят',
    'Мама помыла раму',
    'Маме моет мылом раму',
]

sa = " ".join(a)

# веса похожести для каждого словосочетания
w = [(s, similarity(sa, s),) for s in b]
print(w)

# сортировка в убывающем порядке по весам
c = sorted(w, key=lambda el: -el[1])
print(c)

# Топ 3 с коэффициентами
print(c[:3])

# Топ 3
print([s[0] for s in c[:3]])
```

Результаты работы варианта 3:

```
[('человек развивает свой ум', 0.2564102564102564), ('мама любит котят', 0.4666666666666667), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 0.6285714285714286), ('папа моет рамы', 0.5714285714285714), ('мама установила приложение', 0.45), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0.5185185185185185), ('Мама помыла раму', 0.9333333333333333), ('Маме моет мылом раму', 0.7058823529411765)]
[('Мама помыла раму', 0.9333333333333333), ('Маме моет мылом раму', 0.7058823529411765), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 0.6285714285714286), ('папа моет рамы', 0.5714285714285714), ('Мамочка помыла все рамы и искупала котят', 0.5185185185185185), ('мама любит котят', 0.4666666666666667), ('мама установила приложение', 0.45), ('человек развивает свой ум', 0.2564102564102564)]
[('Мама помыла раму', 0.9333333333333333), ('Маме моет мылом раму', 0.7058823529411765), ('мама ремонтирует раму', 0.6285714285714286)]
['Мама помыла раму', 'Маме моет мылом раму', 'мама ремонтирует раму']
```

Comment: этот код мало применим в реальной жизни. Пример: `"Мамочка помыла все рамы"` - не найдет ни одного совпадения с таким же по смыслу предложением: `"мама мыла раму"`

Comment: в комменте под вопросом написано:  `Нужно полное совпадение по словам, без окончаний и видоизменения слов`

Comment: `совпадение по словам, без окончаний` я понимаю именно так - сравнение нормализованных слов...

Comment: я понял по другому "без видоизменения слов", т.е. окончания не меняются

Comment: я задал автору [уточняющий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172217/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-2-list/1172240?noredirect=1#comment2036790_1172217) - давайте подождем его ответа...

Comment: добавил 2-ой вариант с нормализацией основанной на pymorphy2

Comment: @Rufat Если вы делаете `lower` словам из второго списка, тогда делайте его уж и для первого списка тоже

Comment: @Rufat `import pymorphy2` надо в код добавить, приведённый код должен запускаться без дополнительных телодвижений. И если входной текст будет длинный, рекомендуется вынести использование `morphy.parse(w)[0].normal_form` в отдельную функцию, которая обёрнута в декоратор `lru_cache`, это сильно ускорит код, ибо нормализация - очень затратная по времени функция.

Comment: исправил: 1. добавил `import pymorphy2`; 2. lower добавил в первом варианте 3. во втором варианте lower лишний, убрал. 4. Насчет `lru_cache` согласен, но это уже детали реализации.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть:

Comment: во второй вариант добавил функцию `normalize` с декоратором `lru_cache`

Comment: @Rufat Вот теперь совсем красивый код! Хотя я бы так сильно на `maxsize` не экономил, но это уже совсем мелочи )

Comment: В решении без нормализации `import pymorphy2` не нужен )

Comment: извините, запарился, import убрал

Comment: Спасибо огромное, круто и быстро. Но к сожалению не совсем то.  У меня много значений будет и мне как-то на преобразовать по процентам.Я не совсем корректно поставил условия( Пример ниже:                                                                                                                          
   
import difflib

def similarity(s1, s2):
  normalized1 = s1.lower()
  normalized2 = s2.lower()
  matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, normalized1, normalized2)
  return matcher.ratio()

similarity('мама', 'мама') Результат: 1

Comment: добавил 3-ий вариант с использованием вашего кода с использованием библиотеки `difflib`

Comment: То что надо, спасибо. А можно попросить еще чтобы не только процент выводил но и значения попадающие в топ 3. Спасибо.

Comment: @АнтонКузменков Добавлено отображение только строк из Топ 3.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм:

- сначала нормализуем слова - приводим все слова в нормальную форму (именительный падеж, настоящее время, etc.)
- отбрасываем стоп-слова
- строим *разреженную* бинарную матрицу (one hot encoding) для 5000 - 10000 наиболее часто употребляемых слов
- далее можно считать косинусное расстояние между векторами (строками матрицы) и выбираем N векторов с наименьшим расстоянием

PS попробую набросать небольшой рабочий пример когда появится больше свободного времени

Comment: Ну это решение для больших данных. Нужно ли оно автору? ))

Comment: А то если речь за большие тексты, так тогда надо какой-нибудь FastText уже подтягивать, а не это всё

Comment: @CrazyElf, `Нужно ли оно автору?` - это автору вопроса решать